# how to copy XML Element content to another xml file using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to copy some data in one xml file to another xml file. I have tried many things without any success.

1.xml

```
<head><meta name="charset" content="utf-8"/></head>
```

2.xml file:

```
<dc:identifier id="uuid">123456789</dc:identifier>
```

output File Like:

```
  <head>
      <meta name="dtb:uid" content="123456789"/>
      <meta name="dtb:depth" content="1"/>
      <meta name="dtb:totalPageCount" content="0"/>
      <meta name="dtb:maxPageNumber" content="0"/>
   </head>
```

XSLT file:

```
    <xsl:template match="html:head">
<head>
<meta name="dtb:uid" content="{html:meta[@name='dc:identifier']/@content}"/>
<meta name="dtb:depth" content="{max(//html:li/count(ancestor::html:li))+1}"/>
<xsl:variable name="totalPageCount" select="count(//html:nav[@epub:type='page-list']/html:ol/html:li)"/>
<meta name="dtb:totalPageCount" content="{$totalPageCount}"/>
<xsl:variable name="maxPageNumber" select="number((//html:nav[@epub:type='page-list']/html:ol/html:li)[last()])"/>
<meta name="dtb:maxPageNumber" content="{if (string($maxPageNumber)='NaN') then $totalPageCount else $maxPageNumber}"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="html:meta[not(@name='dc:identifier')]"/>
</head>
</xsl:template>
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do it?

Comment: Do you have 2 XML files and want to copy data from one XML to another XML?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using anything from 1.xml. Why do you involve it at all? You should try and be clear with your requirements.

Comment: i'm defining all the code from what we want required.. but we want 'dc:identifier' content. the content is not mentioned in 1st xml so i'm trying to export from another file.. how to export the content. please let me know any solution

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the shared XSLT code is being applied on `3.xml` (which is not shared), you can get the value of `dc:identifier` from `2.xml` into the XSLT code by using the `document()` function.

Please modify the below XSLT code

```
<meta name="dtb:uid" content="{html:meta[@name='dc:identifier']/@content}"/>
```

to

```
<meta name="dtb:uid" content="{document('2.xml')/dc:identifier}"/>
```

Please ensure you have all the namespaces properly mapped in the XSLT.

Comment: in 1st xml there is no related element. and i'm giving 2nd xml element and it will created to 3rd xml file

Comment: Please update the question explaining the requirement in detail, otherwise it is guessing game. Additionally provide sample of all 3 XMLs with the desired output so that the solution providers can understand the relation between the input and output.

Comment: i'm updating 3 xml files with XSLT code.. please correct the mistake

Comment: Namespace prefix 'dc' has not been declared error occurred.
I mentioned namespace in stylesheet **'exclude-result-prefixes="#all"'**

Comment: Namespace declaration should be `xmlns:dc="http://something.com"` where `something` will correspond to whatever namespace has been declared in the XML. The `exclude-result-prefixes` is used to not add the prefix to the elements in the output XML. Please read more the XML namespaces.

Comment: **xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"** error cleared but data is not copying to output XML. just exucated as **<meta name="dtb:uid" content=""/>**

Comment: the two files are with in the archive